# How to flag names?

Tags: discussion, flagging, specific-user, display-names

I remember discussions, but a quick google didn't give me an answer to how to flag names that should be changed. In any case, a mod probably wants to have a look at [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/160470/prostitute?__=1787809921).

Comment: Be prepared for the moderators rejecting your flag, though. It might happen.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I'm not too invested (user is screaming for attention which I guess I gave him), but would have thought that this is solidly beyond what's ok. As I said before though, I would never want to be a mod and have to deal with this kind of stuff.

Comment: The comments [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/858390/) by this "I am so cool" user are even more repulsive than the name they chose, if you ask me.

Comment: @Did: I feel the same way. I had a reply to the "comeback" written and was on the verge of copying it in...when my phone died (batts). Probably for the better. :)

Comment: What was the original name? It says their name is "Prostitute" now

Comment: Very curious, I hope you still remember after $7$ years

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- If the user has $>0$ posts, flag one of their posts and explain the problem.
- If the user has $0$ posts, flag one of your posts and explain the problem.
- If you also have $0$ posts, flag any post and explain the problem.

Comment: What if the user and oneself have 0 posts?

Comment: @quid I originally thought that could not be the case, seeing as one needs 15 points to flag. But with the association bonus... edited.